# Running Express in Grunt

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs

I'd like to run an Express server which would serve both the backend (usual Node application, doing REST etc) and the frontend.

Now, I've found `grunt-express-server` which seems to be able to do the first thing (starting up my `server.js` script) but offers no options for configuring the static files.

I've also found `grunt-express-middleware` which seems to be doing the opposite, you can configure your folders for static content but it lacks support for server script...

Comment: Why not use the first one and simply configure your static servers in the server script?

Comment: `grunt-express-middleware` does support a custom server script though, via the undocumented `server: "path/to/server.js"` option.

Comment: tried configuring from the server.js as well, although that would be less desirable as doing it from the grunt script or configuration.

Comment: Yes, I've found the server option (lib/util.js), I will give that a go tonight, thanks!

Comment: You'll actually have to write a custom server script if you want to run express 4 as the out of the box app uses bundled middleware.  Given that, it seems to make more sense to configure your server separately, decoupling it from grunt, even if you run it with a grunt task.  But I'm sure you have your reasons.